# Finding Myhill-Nerode relation to get equivalence classes

Tags: regular-language, dfa, equivalence

Fix strings `x` and `y`, `|x| < |y| = n`. For any 2 strings of different lengths, there is a DFA with `O(logn)` states that accept `x` and rejects `y`. Prove that this DFA exists.

My approach: I tried to find such a DFA and one obv one is with `2n` states that accept `x` and rejects `y`. and now I know we use Myhill Nerode relations to minimize DFA but I have no idea how to find the equivalence classes so that I can minimize this DFA.

Comment: Perhaps discriminate X and Y based on the prime factors of their lengths?